# Norms and empty sets

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

If f =0 almost everywhere in I then f=0 in  L1(I)  "the space of lebesgue integrable functions over I".

Why dont we say f=0 almost everywhere in L1(I)?

Comment: The norm is just a real number, not a function.

Comment: When we say $f=0$ in $L^1$ we are thinking of $f$ as an equivalence class of functions.  Our conclusion "$f=0$ in $L^1$" means that the equivalence class of $f$ is the equivalence class of $0$. Some texts may start with some notation for equivalence classes, but after a few pages switch to using $f$ both for the function and for the equivalence class.

Comment: Why don't we say the equivalence class of f equals the equivalence class of 0 almost everywhere too?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).